# How can I use an Azure DevOps repository in another repository? Are there external references?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I am facing an issue that should be relatively simple, but I struggle to find a solution. I have a collection of projects in Azure DevOps and each project equals one of our products. In order to clean-up our projects, I want to move shared or common components into a new Azure DevOps project and reference this new project in the other projects.

When a developer checks out a project, I want them to also automatically check out the shared project and when they commit changes, it should go to the respective project. I am sure there is a good guide for it, but I fail to find one.

In SVN I was achieving this by using SVN Externals and I think GitHub has something similar, but I do not find an option for external project references in Azure DevOps. Am I blind or am I researching the wrong tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a developer checks out a project, I want them to also automatically check out the shared project and when they commit changes,

You can consider using [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to achieve this feature.

Here are the steps to add submodule to git:

```
git clone {clone URL}

git submodule add {repository url}

git add .

git commit -m "commit message"

git push
```

Then you will see the .gitmodules and reference repo name file in the project.

for example:

[image]

When you checkout the repo, you can use the option: `submodules: true` in Azure Pipeline.

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: true
```

Classic Pipeline:

[image]

You can use the following command to checkout the submodule to local machine:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules repourl
```

In this case, it will automatically checkout the self project and the shared project.

On the other hand, if you are using YAML pipeline, you can also consider using the Repo resource: [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will test it as soon as I can. I got an urgent task in that I need to resolve first. I will check it as soon as I can! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BeRo Will wait for your response. Feel free to let me know if it can work for you

Comment: More important tasks came up that need to be done first. I hope to do it early next week.

Comment: Never mind, Take your time. Will wait for your feedback

Comment: It worked absolutely flawless. The only tiny addition I have for people who might find this thread in the future: Use " -b feature" when cloning a branch with the name "feature" instead of cloning the main branch.